# Необработанное исключение по адресу.Задача на двумерные массивы

Tags: c++, массивы, меню, матрицы

Задача: дана целочисленная квадратная матрица. Определить:

1) Сумму элементов в тех строках, которые не содержат отрицательных элементов;

2) минимум среди сумм элементов диагоналей, параллельных главной диагонали матрицы.

Решение нужно сделать в виде интерактивного меню. Вроде все работает, но при выводе решения ошибка:

> Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x011C8BD9 в ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0xFDFDFE05.

Мое решение:

```
#include "stdafx.h" 
#include "stdio.h" 
#include "locale.h" 
#include "conio.h" 
#include <math.h> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip> 
#include <time.h> 

double rnd(int range_min, int range_max) {
    return (double)rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1)*(range_max - range_min) + range_min;
}
double **arr, **new_arr;
using namespace std;
int i, j, n, m, x, y, sum, s, mains, sides, 
zaglushka = 0, //заглушка на решение и вывод 
k = 0; //переменная для проверки корректного ввода 
char button, //кнопка выхода 
button_key_ran, //кнопка выбора режима ввода 
button_sdvig, //кнопка выбора режима сдвига 
input_perem[256];//переменная, в которую вводятся первоначальные данные для проверки 


int menu() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    system("cls");
    int menu_num = 0;
    cout << " Меню" << endl;
    cout << "1.Ввод"
        << "2.Решение\n"
        << "3.Вывод\n "
        << "4. О программе\n "
        << "5.Справка\n"
        << "6.Выход\n" << endl;
    while (menu_num == 0) {
        k = 0;
        cout << "Выберите вариант: ";
        cin >> input_perem;
        for (i = 0; i < strlen(input_perem); i++) {
            if (input_perem[i] <= '0' || input_perem[i] >= '7') {
                k++;
            }
        }
        if (strlen(input_perem) > 1) {
            k++;
        }
        if (k == 0) {
            menu_num = atof(input_perem);
        }
    }
    return menu_num;
}

int input() {
    zaglushka = 1;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        delete[] arr[i];
        delete[] new_arr[i];
    }
    delete[] arr;
    delete[] new_arr;
    cout << "1. С клавиатуры" << endl;
    cout << "2. Генератором случайных чисел" << endl;
    button_key_ran = '0';
    while (button_key_ran != '1' && button_key_ran != '2')
    {
        button_key_ran = _getch();
    }
    if (button_key_ran == '1') {
        n = 0;
        while (n == 0) {
            k = 0;
            cout << "Введите кол-во вещественных строк квадратной матрицы (1>...>100): ";
            cin >> input_perem;
            for (i = 0; i < strlen(input_perem); i++) {
                if (input_perem[i] < '0' || input_perem[i] > '9') {
                    k++;
                }
            }
            if (k == 0 && atof(input_perem) < 100 && atof(input_perem) > 1) {
                n = atof(input_perem);
            }
        }
        m = 0;
        while (m == 0) {
            k = 0;
            cout << "Введите кол-во вещественных столбцов квадратной матрицы (1>...>100): ";
            cin >> input_perem;
            for (i = 0; i < strlen(input_perem); i++) {
                if (input_perem[i] < '0' || input_perem[i] > '9') {
                    k++;
                }
            }
            if (k == 0 && atof(input_perem) < 100 && atof(input_perem) > 1) {
                m = atof(input_perem);
            }
        }
        cout << "Введите элементы массива |A[i][j]|<1e300" << endl;
        arr = new double *[n];
        new_arr = new double *[n];
        for (i = 0; i<n; i++) {
            arr[i] = new double[n];
            new_arr[i] = new double[n];
        }
        //ввод с клавиатуры 
        for (i = 0; i<n; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = 0;
                while (arr[i][j] == 0) {
                    k = 0;
                    cout << "A[" << i + 1 << "][" << j + 1 << "]: ";
                    cin >> input_perem;
                    for (int x = 0; x < strlen(input_perem); x++) {
                        if (x == 0 && input_perem[x] == '-') {
                            k--;
                        }
                        if (input_perem[x] == 'e') {
                            k--;
                        }
                        if ((input_perem[x] < '0' || input_perem[x] > '9') && input_perem[x] != ',') {
                            k++;
                        }
                    }
                    if (k == 0 && atof(input_perem) < 1e300 && atof(input_perem) > -1e300) {
                        arr[i][j] = 1;
                    }
                }
                arr[i][j] = atof(input_perem);
            }
        }
    }
    if (button_key_ran == '2') {
        //ввод рандомно 
        n = 0;
        while (n == 0) {
            k = 0;
            cout << "Введите кол-во вещественных строк квадратной матрицы (1>...>100): ";
            cin >> input_perem;
            for (i = 0; i < strlen(input_perem); i++) {
                if (input_perem[i] < '0' || input_perem[i] > '9') {
                    k++;
                }
            }
            if (k == 0 && atof(input_perem)<100 && atof(input_perem)>1) {
                n = atof(input_perem);
            }
        }
        m = 0;
        while (m == 0) {
            k = 0;
            cout << "Введите кол-во вещественных столбцов квадратной матрицы (1>...>100): ";
            cin >> input_perem;
            for (i = 0; i < strlen(input_perem); i++) {
                if
                    (input_perem[i] < '0' || input_perem[i] > '9') {
                    k++;
                }
            }
            if (k == 0 && atof(input_perem)<100 && atof(input_perem)>1) {
                m = atof(input_perem);
            }
        }
        arr = new double *[n];
        new_arr = new double *[n];
        for (i = 0; i<n; i++) {
            arr[i] = new double[n];
            new_arr[i] = new double[n];
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = rnd(-100, 100);
            }
        }

    }
    return 0;
}

int solution() {
    if (zaglushka == 1 || zaglushka == 3) {
        zaglushka = 2;
        sum = 0;
        for (unsigned j = 0; j<n; j++)
        {
            bool flag = true;
            int sumincol = 0;
            for (unsigned i = 0; i<m; i++)
            {
                if (arr[i][j]<0)
                {
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                }
                sumincol += arr[i][j];
            }
            sum += sumincol*flag;
        }
cout << "Решение выполнено" << endl;
    }

    else {
        cout << "Введите данные" << endl;
    }
    cout << endl << "Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу" << endl;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}

int mainsum(int x, int y) //сумма элементов диагонали параллельной главной 
{
    s = 0;
    for (; x<n&&y<m; x++, y++) {
        s += arr[x][y];
    }
    return s;
}
int sidesum(int x, int y)//Сумма Элементов Диагонали Паралельной Побочной 
{
    s = 0;
    for (; x<n&&y<m; x--, y++) {
        s += arr[x][y];
    }
    return s;
}


int output() {
    if (zaglushka == 2 || zaglushka == 3) {
        zaglushka = 3;
        cout << "Исходная матрица:" << endl;
        for (unsigned i = 0; i<n; i++)
        {
            for (unsigned j = 0; j<m; j++)cout << setw(7) << arr[i][j] << ' ';
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << "Сумма элементов в столбцах не содержащих отрицательных значений:" << sum << endl;
        // Проход по диагоналям в верхнем треугольнике 
        for (int i = 0; i<m; i++)printf("%d\t", mainsum(i, 0)); printf("\n");
        // Проход по диагоналям в нижнем треугольнике 
        for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)printf("%d\t", sidesum(0, i)); printf("\n");
        printf("\n");
        // Проход по диагоналям в верхнем треугольнике 
        for (int i = 0; i<m; i++)printf("%d\t", sidesum(i, 0)); printf("\n");
        // Проход по диагоналям в нижнем треугольнике 
        for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)printf("%d\t", sidesum(0, i)); printf("\n");


    }
    else {
        cout << "Выполните решение" << endl;
    }
    cout << endl << "Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу" << endl;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
int about() {
    cout<< endl << "Версия 1.1.0"
        << endl
        << "2017 г"
        << endl << "Выполнил Рыболовлев Давид" << endl;
    cout << endl << "Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу" << endl;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
int help() {
    cout
        << "Дана целочисленная квадратная матрица.Определить:" << endl
        << "1.) сумму элементов в тех строках, которые не содержат отрицательных элементов;" << endl
        << "2.) минимум среди сумм элементов диагоналей, параллельных главной диагонали матрицы." << endl
        << endl;
    cout << endl << "Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу" << endl;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    while (button != '6') {

        int variant = menu();

        switch (variant) {
        case 1:
            input();
            break;
        case 2:
            solution();
            break;
        case 3:
            output();
            break;
        case 4:
            about();
            break;
        case 5:
            help();
            break;
        case 6:
            return 0;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А в чём заключается ваш вопрос?

Comment: Ошибка в программе. Выполняются нормально все действия кроме вывода ответа. То есть загоняю матрицу. Решаю. Читаю справку и т д.Но при выводе решение ошибка Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x011C8BD9 в ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0xFDFDFE05.

Comment: [Добавте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/770330/edit) сообщение об ошибке прямо в вопрос.

Comment: Дак вы можете мне помочь?

Comment: Так вы хоть скажите, где именно, в какой строке это вылетает, при каких данных?

Comment: "ConsoleApplication1.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr120d.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"ConsoleApplication1.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr120d.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"ConsoleApplication1.exe" (Win32). Выгружено "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr120d.dll"
Первый этап обработки исключения по адресу 0x011C8BD9 в ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0xFDFDFE05.
Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x011C8BD9 в ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа

Comment: это сведения из откладки

Comment: В строках `arr[i] = new double[n];` и `new_arr[i] = new double[n];` замените `n` на `m`. Если поможет — распишу в ответе способ быстрой диагностики подобных ошибок.

Comment: Не помогло все равно вылазит ошибка. Я полагаю в этих строках.

Comment: int sidesum(int x, int y)//Сумма Элементов Диагонали Паралельной Побочной 
{
 s = 0;
 for (; x<n&&y<m; x--, y++) {
  s += arr[x][y];
 }
 return s;
}
for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)printf("%d\t", sidesum(0, i)); printf("\n");
  printf("\n");

Comment: Как бы то не было, у вас где-то идёт чтение за границами какого-то массива указателей (`FD` и `FE` в адресе из ошибки — это сторожевые значения, «забор», позволяющий отследить запись за пределы выделенной области. То есть вы считываете этот мусор как значение указателя, затем разыменовываете и пытаетесь что-то по нему прочитать).

Answer (score 1):

Стандартная библиотека обеспечивает безопасность исключений, и там есть такой хороший класс valarray, специализированный для численных методов. Вот если знать этот класс, то можно решить задачу легче и без головных болей. Я напишу вам для примера решение первой задачи

```
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>
using std::valarray;
using std::slice;
bool needful(const valarray<int>& cv)
{
   for (size_t i = 0; i < cv.size(); ++i) {
       if (cv[i] < 0)
           return false;
   }
   return true;
}

int main()
{  
    // инициализация для примера
    const int row = 5;
    int m[row * row] = {3,  7,  -2, 55, -33,
                        4,  8,  11, 12,  23,
                        4,  6,  14, -9,  13,
                        23, 3,  88, -20, 17,
                        67, 55, 44,  5,  1 };
    //task[0]:
    valarray<int> matrix(m, row * row);
    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
        valarray<int> v = matrix[slice(i * row, row, 1)];
        if (needful(v))
            std::cout << "sum of  " << i + 1 << "  row == " << v.sum() <<std::endl;
    }
    //вторую задачу решать можно с помощью общих срезов gslice
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот все починил. Работает исправно. Юзайте))

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "locale.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include <math.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include <time.h>

double rnd(int range_min, int range_max) {
    return (double)rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1)*(range_max - range_min) + range_min;
}

double **arr, **new_arr, maxSum, underDiagonal, aboveDiagonal;
using namespace std;
int i, j, n, m, x, y, sum, s,
zaglushka = 0, //заглушка на решение и вывод
k = 0; //переменная для проверки корректного ввода
char button, //кнопка выхода
button_key_ran, //кнопка выбора режима ввода
button_sdvig, //кнопка выбора режима сдвига
input_perem[256];//переменная, в которую вводятся первоначальные данные для проверки

int menu() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    system("cls");
    int menu_num = 0;
    cout << "Программа Двумерный массив. Автор-составитель:  студент ИКТ-11 Рыболовлев Давид" << endl
        << "Дана целочисленная квадратная матрица.Определить:" << endl
        << "1) сумму элементов в тех строках, которые не содержат отрицательных элементов;" << endl
        << "2) минимум среди сумм элементов диагоналей, параллельных главной диагонали матрицы." << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << " Меню" << endl;
    cout << " 1.Ввод\n"
        << " 2.Решение\n"
        << " 3.Вывод\n "
        << "4.О программе\n "
        << "5.Справка\n"
        << " 6.Выход\n" << endl;
    while (menu_num == 0) {
        k = 0;
        cout << "Выберите вариант: ";
        cin >> input_perem;
        for (i = 0; i < strlen(input_perem); i++) {
            if (input_perem[i] <= '0' || input_perem[i] >= '7') {
            k++;
            }
        }
        if (strlen(input_perem) > 1) {
            k++;
        }
        if (k == 0) {
            menu_num = atof(input_perem);
        }
    }
    return menu_num;
}

int input() {
    zaglushka = 1;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        delete[] arr[i];
        delete[] new_arr[i];
    }
    delete[] arr;
    delete[] new_arr;
    cout << "1. С клавиатуры" << endl;
    cout << "2. Генератором случайных чисел" << endl;
    button_key_ran = '0';
    while (button_key_ran != '1' && button_key_ran != '2')
    {
        button_key_ran = _getch();
    }
    if (button_key_ran == '1') {
        n = 0;
        while (n == 0) {
            k = 0;
            cout << "Введите кол-во вещественных строк квадратной матрицы (1>...>100): ";
            cin >> input_perem;
            for (i = 0; i < strlen(input_perem); i++) {
                if (input_perem[i] < '0' || input_perem[i] > '9') {
                    k++;
                }
            }
            if (k == 0 && atof(input_perem) < 100 && atof(input_perem) > 1) {
                n = atof(input_perem);
            }
        }
        m = 0;
        while (m == 0) {
            k = 0;
            cout << "Введите кол-во вещественных столбцов квадратной матрицы (1>...>100): ";
            cin >> input_perem;
            for (i = 0; i < strlen(input_perem); i++) {
                if (input_perem[i] < '0' || input_perem[i] > '9') {
                    k++;
                }
            }
            if (k == 0 && atof(input_perem) < 100 && atof(input_perem) > 1) {
                m = atof(input_perem);
            }
        }
        cout << "Введите элементы массива |A[i][j]|<1e300" << endl;
        arr = new double *[n];
        new_arr = new double *[n];
        for (i = 0; i<n; i++) {
            arr[i] = new double[n];
            new_arr[i] = new double[n];
        }
        //ввод с клавиатуры
        for (i = 0; i<n; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = 0;
                while (arr[i][j] == 0) {
                    k = 0;
                    cout << "A[" << i + 1 << "][" << j + 1 << "]: ";
                    cin >> input_perem;
                    for (int x = 0; x < strlen(input_perem); x++) {
                        if (x == 0 && input_perem[x] == '-') {
                            k--;
                        }
                        if (input_perem[x] == 'e') {
                            k--;
                        }
                        if ((input_perem[x] < '0' || input_perem[x] > '9') && input_perem[x] != ',') {
                            k++;
                        }
                    }
                    if (k == 0 && atof(input_perem) < 1e300 && atof(input_perem) > -1e300) {
                        arr[i][j] = 1;
                    }
                }
                arr[i][j] = atof(input_perem);
            }
        }
    }
    if (button_key_ran == '2') {
        //ввод рандомно
        n = 0;
        while (n == 0) {
            k = 0;
            cout << "Введите кол-во вещественных строк квадратной матрицы (1>...>100): ";
            cin >> input_perem;
            for (i = 0; i < strlen(input_perem); i++) {
                if (input_perem[i] < '0' || input_perem[i] > '9') {
                    k++;
                }
            }
            if (k == 0 && atof(input_perem)<100 && atof(input_perem)>1) {
                n = atof(input_perem);
            }
        }
        m = 0;
        while (m == 0) {
            k = 0;
            cout << "Введите кол-во вещественных столбцов квадратной матрицы (1>...>100): ";
            cin >> input_perem;
            for (i = 0; i < strlen(input_perem); i++) {
                if
                    (input_perem[i] < '0' || input_perem[i] > '9') {
                    k++;
                }
            }
            if (k == 0 && atof(input_perem)<100 && atof(input_perem)>1) {
                m = atof(input_perem);
            }
        }
        arr = new double *[n];
        new_arr = new double *[n];
        for (i = 0; i<n; i++) {
            arr[i] = new double[n];
            new_arr[i] = new double[n];
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = rnd(-100, 100);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int solution() {
    if (zaglushka == 1 || zaglushka == 3) {
        zaglushka = 2;
        sum = 0;
        for (unsigned j = 0; j<n; j++)
        {
            bool flag = true;
            int sumincol = 0;
            for (unsigned i = 0; i<m; i++)
            {
                if (arr[i][j]<0)
                {
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                }
                sumincol += arr[i][j];
            }
            sum += sumincol*flag;
        }
        /*фыафыпфпркпфукпфук*/
        maxSum = 10000000, underDiagonal = 0, aboveDiagonal = 0;
        for (unsigned int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            underDiagonal = 0;
            for (unsigned int j = 0, k = j; j < n - i; j++, k++) {
                underDiagonal += arr[j + i][k];
            }
            maxSum = (maxSum > underDiagonal) ? underDiagonal : maxSum;
        }
        for (unsigned int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            aboveDiagonal = 0;
            for (unsigned int j = 0, k = j; j < n - i; j++, k++) {
                aboveDiagonal += arr[j][k + i];
            }
            maxSum = (maxSum > aboveDiagonal) ? aboveDiagonal : maxSum;
        }
        cout << "Решение выполнено" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Введите данные" << endl;
    }
    cout << endl << "Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу" << endl;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
/*
int mainsum(int x, int y) //сумма элементов диагонали параллельной главной

{

s = 0;

for (; x<n&&y<m; x++, y++) {

s += arr[x][y];

}

return s;

}

int sidesum(int x, int y)//Сумма Элементов Диагонали Паралельной Побочной

{

s = 0;

for (; x<n&&y<m; x--, y++) {

s += arr[x][y];

}

return s;

}
*/
int output() {
    if (zaglushka == 2 || zaglushka == 3) {
        zaglushka = 3;
        cout << "Исходная матрица:" << endl;
        for (unsigned i = 0; i<n; i++)
        {
            for (unsigned j = 0; j<m; j++)cout << setw(7) << arr[i][j] << ' ';
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << "Сумма элементов в столбцах не содержащих отрицательных значений:" << sum << endl;
        cout << "Минимум среди сумм элементов диагоналей, параллельных главной диагонали: " << maxSum << endl;
        /*
        // Проход по диагоналям в верхнем треугольнике

        for (int i = 0; i<m; i++)printf("%d\t", mainsum(i, 0)); printf("\n");

        // Проход по диагоналям в нижнем треугольнике

        for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)printf("%d\t", sidesum(0, i)); printf("\n");

        printf("\n");

        // Проход по диагоналям в верхнем треугольнике

        for (int i = 0; i<m; i++)printf("%d\t", sidesum(i, 0)); printf("\n");

        // Проход по диагоналям в нижнем треугольнике

        for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)printf("%d\t", sidesum(0, i)); printf("\n");


        */
    }
    else {
        cout << "Выполните решение" << endl;
    }
    cout << endl << "Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу" << endl;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}

int about() {
cout << endl << "Версия 1.1.0"
<< endl
<< "2017 г"
<< endl << "Выполнил Рыболовлев Давид" << endl;
cout << endl << "Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу" << endl;
_getch();
return 0;
}
int help() {
    cout
        << "Дана целочисленная квадратная матрица.Определить:" << endl
        << "1) сумму элементов в тех строках, которые не содержат отрицательных элементов;" << endl
        << "2) минимум среди сумм элементов диагоналей, параллельных главной диагонали матрицы." << endl
        << endl;
    cout << endl << "Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу" << endl;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    while (button != '6') {
        int variant = menu();
        switch (variant) {
        case 1:
            input();
            break;
        case 2:
            solution();
            break;
        case 3:
            output();
            break;
        case 4:
            about();
            break;
        case 5:
            help();
            break;
        case 6:
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```